# Creating and filling an array in for each loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, each

```js
//is there any way to do this

public Entry[] getArray(SimpleHashtable table) {

  Entry[] data;

  for (Entry k: table) {

    //do something here

  }

  return data; //array that contains all elements stored in table
}
```

Is there a way to create and fill array with elements in for each loop?

Explained in short:

I have made class SimpleHashtable that stores objects, it implements Iterable.
Now I have to code method that returns an array of elements that are stored in that SimpleHashtable, and first idea that came to mind is to iterate over SimpleHashtable and fill array one element at the time, but I cant find any example of that.

If would like to avoid putting elements in a list in the meantime until I have iterated over SimpleHashtable (seems messy).

I know that arrays in Java aren't resizable, and that seems to make things difficult.

Comment: you might want to post code, as is it's difficult to tell what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class `SimpleHashtable` has a method `size()` to get the number of elements (which you need to size your array). You could then iterate with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (as requested) with something like,

```
SimpleHashtable<Object> sh;
// ...
Object[] arr = new Object[sh.size()];
int pos = 0;
for (Object obj : sh) {
  arr[pos++] = obj;
}
```

Comment: Adding size() as functionality in SimpleHashtable with code like this seems to be simplest way